# After update AGP to 4.2.2 from 4.1.3 - get error "Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalProductionRelease' "

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, lint, android-lint

besides AGP update, updated compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 30.

build success, if set

```
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

else i get

```
Execution failed for task ‘:app:lintVitalProductionRelease’.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ‘:app:debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath’.
   > A problem occurred configuring project ‘:core-testing’.
      > java.lang.IllegalStateException: Accessing GradleBuildProject.Builder through AnalyticsConfiguratorService is not allowed after AnalyticsService is created.
```

compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 30
gradle 7.0.2

Any idea, guys?

Comment: Hi Alexandr, have you gotten it working?

Answer (score 22):

It may be AGP bug. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/226095015

**At Oct 9, 2021:**

I solved the same problem by change the configure:

`gradle.properties`

```
#org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

**After Nov 4, 2021:**

you can upgrade AGP to the latest version e.g. 7.3.x. it won't happen.

**April 12, 2023:**

I found a new solution.
edit the settings file at `~/.android/analytics.settings`

```
- {"userId":"・・・・","hasOptedIn":true,"・・・・
+ {"userId":"・・・・","hasOptedIn":false,"・・・・
```

change `hasOptedIn` from `true` to `false`.

before gradle task execute, you should **stop** gradle by

```
./gradlew --stop
```

[found by this link.](https://qiita.com/ko2ic/items/a41a0457e54a39aacfe2)

Comment: What to update? AGP/compile/buildTools/minSdk/Gradle?

Comment: @TWiStErRob would you like to try the latest solution?

Comment: `hasOptedIn` trick solved it for me.

Comment: Thank you! hasOptedIn solved the ploblem